# Looking for a list of JavaScript error codes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is there a list of JavaScript or jQuery error codes (the kind which, for example, MySQL and MariaDB have)?

I have received an `Error 5001`, and I have no idea what it means. Will elaborate, if it turns out to be necessary.

---

**EDIT**

The reason I'm asking is this. A webapp which I'm partially involved in has recently started returning unusual responses from jQuery AJAX calls. Response is

`Error 5001`

I have never seen something like this before, and googling for a solution returned [this old link](https://coderanch.com/t/505007/languages/error-client-side).

Even after receiving steps to reproduce the error, my team and I haven't been able to do so.

The code is setup like this:

**jQuery**

```
$('#someId').on('change',function() {
    var id = $('#otherId').val(); // this is a hidden input field
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/check.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {valId:id}
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data=="ok") {
                $('#someId').removeClass('blue').addClass('green');
            } else {
                $('#someId').removeClass('green').addClass('blue');
            }
        },
        error: function(desc, err) {
            console.log("Details: "+ JSON.stringify(desc) + "\r\nError: " + JSON.stringify(err);
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$id = preg_replace('/\D/','',(int)$_POST['id']);

if($id < 1 || $id != $_POST['id']) {
    echo "no";
    die();
}

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$mysqli->query("UPDATE mytable SET dateupdated = '".$date."' WHERE id = $id");

if($mysqli->affected_rows < 1) {
    echo "no.";
    die();
}

echo "ok";
```

Error logging has been disabled globally, and there's nothing from the PHP side of things, which would printout this error.

If it's of any relevance, the server on which the app is hosted has recently started responding sluggishly, and returning a query such as

`SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY datemodified DESC LIMIT 10`

requires the users to wait for **up to 3 minutes**. The database has been optimized and repaired when these issues starting happening, but that didn't help. DB has also been tested on two other unrelated servers (same PHP and MariaDB version), and the same query performed quickly, as expected.

Comment: can you post a screenshot ?

Comment: Neither Javascript nor jQuery have error codes.  Some specific libraries may throw error codes; check their docs.

Comment: Maybe somewhere in your code there is `throw "5001: i wanna confuse you"` ?

Comment: [MDN List of JS Error References](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors) -- no numbered errors, though.

Comment: @JonasW. `$(this).trigger('confusion');`

Comment: @Tareq Hope the code snippets would do.

Comment: NOTE: you are vulnerable to an SQL injection... use query params. Also, use of `die()`? I *really* hope you're trying to learn out of a (obviously awful/outdated) book and that isn't production code...

Comment: `error: function(desc, err) { console.log("Details: "+ JSON.stringify(desc) + "\r\nError: " + JSON.stringify(err); }` - tends to imply that **Error: 5001** is specific to *ajax/check.php* so I'd look at that file first.

Comment: @JaredSmith According to php.net, `die()` is equivalent to `exit()`. I'm just using it to stop further code exectuion after echoing a response which I want to use for AJAX. As far as the SQL injection is concerned, am I not in the clear by parsing the response so it contains only digits? Or is that a thing for a new question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing an extensive search through all the files in the entire webapp, it turned out that the error came from a custom error handler in an old custom JS library. Apologies for wasting everybody's time.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/javascript-run-time-errors - This might be what you are looking for if you are doing something with Windows Apps.

In your case Error 5001 could be - `5001    Number expected`

Comment: That's for Windows Store Apps written in JavaScript, and is almost certainly not what the OP is asking about.

Comment: OP didn't specify what he is coding - so I searched for answer to 'Javascript' and 'Error 5001'.....

Comment: I get that, but that's when you leave a comment on the question asking for clarification ("Are you trying to write a Windows Store App in JavaScript?") rather than post an answer that *probably* doesn't work (how many people are writing Windows Store Apps in JS?).

Comment: That's fair. FWIW I would have liked to leave a comment as well, but being below 50 reputation does not allow me to do that yet, so I can only provide input by answers or comments on my own answers.

Comment: @NathanBlaine Thanks for the response, but that's not quite what I'm doing. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Answers are supposed to be answers, not comments. The reputation threshold exists for a reason, subverting it this way is a no-no.